# Golang client to perform operations on cdt list in aerospike

Tags: go, aerospike

I wanted to use a list as a bin value in aerospike. So, http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html seems like a good option. But the client examples in golang https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/examples/list_map.go only shows a get and a put.

```
key, _ := as.NewKey(*shared.Namespace, *shared.Set, "listkey1")
client.Delete(shared.WritePolicy, key)

list := []string{"string1", "string2", "string3"}

bin := as.NewBin("listbin1", list)
client.PutBins(shared.WritePolicy, key, bin)

record, err := client.Get(shared.Policy, key, bin.Name)
shared.PanicOnError(err)
receivedList := record.Bins[bin.Name].([]interface{})

validateSize(3, len(receivedList))
validate("string1", receivedList[0])
validate("string2", receivedList[1])
validate("string3", receivedList[2])
```

What about all other APIs mentioned ? Such as how do I append to the list or get count of objects in the list etc. ? Any reference to any documentation would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't expect examples to provide full documentation. Use [the documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go) for that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Flimzy for pointing the documentation. Maybe for future users who come accross this question, the following might help.

To perform a list operation, you need to use the following method and specify the operation:

https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#Client.Operate

The Operate method takes an operation and to get an operation the List*Op methods are used (such as https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#ListAppendOp)